# How to prove this inequality about $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

When I read an analysis book, this book says

> when $x>0$, we have
> $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}x^k<\frac{e^x}{(n+1)!}$.

I get confused here, the author does not explain why this inequality is true, and it is also not apparent to me. I try to use math induction to prove it but fail.
can you give me some hints?

Comment: Plotting these functions in Desmos suggest that this inequality is false. This might be a typo, since a simple application of Taylor's remainder theorem tells us there exists some $y \in (0, x)$ such that
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}x^k = \frac{e^y}{(n+1)!}y^{n+1} < \frac{e^x}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}.$$The $x^{n+1}$ factor may just have been left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality you have given is not true, for instance it fails at $n=1$ and $x=2$. I believe what you're after is
$$\sum_{k\geq n+1}\frac{x^k}{k!}<\frac{x^{n+1}e^x}{(n+1)!}\,\,\forall\,x>0$$
To prove this, we note
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{n+1}e^x}{(n+1)!}&=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{x^{n+1+k}}{k!(n+1)!}\\
&>\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{x^{n+1+k}}{(n+1+k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k\geq n+1}\frac{x^k}{k!}
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you , I think it is a typo in my book.